# What's wrong with my wildcarded custom search in Marklogic with Java API?

Tags: java, json, search, wildcard, marklogic

My aim is to try doing a wildcarded search at Marklogic, using Java.

What I have currently in Marklogic.

```
/articles/1.json
1.json:
[{
  "title":"hello%20world1",
  "content":"article content etc..."
}]

/articles/2.json
2.json:
[{
  "title":"hello world 2",
  "content":"article content etc..."
}]

/articles/3.json
3.json:
[{
  "title":"hello world 3",
  "content":"article content etc..."
}]
```

My Java API

**First Alternative**

```
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
String[] queryOptions = {"case-insensitive","wildcarded"};
QueryDefinition queryDef = qb.value(qb.jsonProperty("title"),
                               FragmentScope.DOCUMENTS,queryOptions 
                               ,100.0,"*"+keyword+"*");
// if possible, can someone explain what does that "weight" property 
// which I set as 100.0 does?
SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle();
queryManager.setPageLength(PAGE_SIZE_MAX);
queryManager.search(queryDef, resultsHandle,0);
```

I tried searching using the term "**world1**"

All the articles are returned. That's not what I wanted. By right only article1 should be returned. Logic seems right, but query does not seems to be working.

So I tried another alternative to test whether is it the options issue or my data issue.

**Second Alternative**

```
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
QueryDefinition queryDef = qb.word(qb.jsonProperty("title"),keyword);
// correct me if i'm wrong, this line will mean it will take the title 
// as long as the title contains the keyword right?
SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle();
queryManager.setPageLength(PAGE_SIZE_MAX);
queryManager.search(queryDef, resultsHandle,0);
```

I tested with the following terms:

- "**hello**", all results returned as expected.
- "**worl**", expected all results to be returned, but none returned
- "**world**", expected all results to be returned, but only article 2 and 3 returned

Therefore, to conclude, as mentioned above, my aim is to do a wildcarded search. An ideal result will be:

- "**wor**", all results returned.

Additionally, are there any ways to ignore that "%20"during the search?

Answer (score 1):

The thing to understand is that you are doing a search here, not a substring match. The other thing to understand is that %20 is just a punctuation mark and some numeric digits when stored in a document. It doesn't mean space.

The second query is easier to understand: it says "get me all documents that have this word in them". What counts as a word depends on how the contents in the document was tokenized in accordance with the language of that document.

So here we have: hello + % + 20world1, hello + world + 2, and hello + world + 3
So hello matches all three, world matches the second and third, and worl matches none of them because that word does not appear in any of them.

The results of your wildcard query depend a lot on what your index settings are. Lacking the right indexes could get you false positives in unindexed search. A look at the query plan will tell you what it is trying to do, based on the indexes available. You'll want to enable 3 character indexes and a word lexicon with the codepoint collation, and then I'd run this as a wildcarded word query rather than as a value query.